# Hot to get element from global array of object in javascript and execute his functions?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a global array

```
var global.DATA=[]
```

and a Class someClass containing a function someFunction.

global.DATA contains objects of class SomeClass

```
global.DATA.push(new SomeClass(someAwesomeData));
```

Now, if i do

```
DATA[0].someFunction()
```

the function of the object gets executed cause DATA[0] is a SomeClass object and someFunction is a function of objects of class SomeClass. So far so good.

If I define a function

```
function getObjectFromDATA(){
   var index = 0;
   return DATA[index];
}
```

it returns DATA[0], but if I do

```
getObjectFromDATA().someFunction()
```

it raises an error, saying that 'someFunction' is not defined, like the one returned is not a SomeClass object. What am I missing?

Comment: How can you be sure that the function returns DATA[0]? 0 is not equal to TRUE!

Comment: Whoops, edited the question, don't care that if. Thank you